# Looking for strong key en/decryption algorithm which will "loudly" fail on corrupt or modified data?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption

I'm looking for a strong key encryption algorithm that has the additional feature that when the encrypted file gets corrupted or tempered with it will fail "loudly"; i.e. it will fail and tell me about it instead of producing garbage as decrypted output.

Ideally one which comes standard with Java. Does AES do this?

Thanks,
Carsten

PS> I know that I can do this manually by additionally computing a hash on the encrypted file, but I'd like to avoid doing that.

[edit: removed "public / private"  as not really necessary for me, and inconsistent as people pointed out]

Comment: [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is symmetric ... you said you need a public / private key

Comment: Please provide more info about scenario. Maybe we can help to find the better solution?

Comment: Agent1891: Good point. How embarrassing, I changed my mind half-way through writing the question without being consistent. I don't need public / private key. Any strong key based encryption will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you want to use public/private key algorithm so asymetric. For example RSA encryption is using PKCS#1 padding. If you use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")` this padding is default. If decryption fails it is very probable that padding will be corrupted. In java you will get BadPaddingException.

Nevertheless **I strongly suggest using hashing (even fast MD5) or simple control sum instead**. Look [how it is done in IPSec](http://book.soundonair.ru/cisco/ch13lev1sec6.html). IPsec uses symmetric encription (DES) and  HMAC (Message Authentication Codes using Hashing) - a mechanism for message authentication using cryptographic hash functions. Maybe, if you don't need to hide data you should use HMAC only?

I can guess that you don't need encryption, but digital signature. In fact digital signature is an encrypted (with private key) hash of a message. Verification is a decryption of this hash and comparation with computed from plaintext message.

**If your provide more detail description then we can help to find the best solution.**

Comment: In short, I guess, the answer is No. I'll use an additional hash.

Answer (score 2):

If you want authenticity of your data, then you could apply a MAC (Message Authentication Code) or a digital signature on your data.

A viable solution using asymmetric public/private keys would be to wrap your data in a SignedData which then itself would be the payload of an EnvelopedData (cf. [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.1)).

Signature validation on your SignedData will loudly fail if somebody tampered with the contents.

If you don't want to involve asymmetric keys, another standardized way to achieve your goal is using the AuthenticatedData structure described in the same RFC. The payload would be your already encrypted data, and the MAC would additionally ensure integrity and authenticity, again failing noticeably if the contents were tampered with.

The advantage of using a standard such as CMS here is a) that libraries already exist that support these features out of the box and b) that you can rely on something that has been tested and analyzed, so you don't run the risk of creating something insecure, something that happens all too easily with these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

I am nearly certain that any cryptographic system that is sensitive to the content (in the way that you want) will be leaking way too much info to be good encryption.

The reason we have specialized, concern specific, algorithms is (imo) precisely for this reason.

It should be a trivial matter for you to provide an interface that includes the message digest in the (compound) plain-text and then apply encryption.  On decryption, your simple wrapper will seek a (fixed) n-byte matter (somewhere in the compound plain-text)

e.g. encrypt this:

```
   +--------------+----------------//----------+
   | digest bytes | content (plain-text)       |
   +--------------+----------------//----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check out PKCS #7, which is also used in S/MIME. It supports strong encryption and authentication, and is widely used and available via many implementing libraries. [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) would be a good Java option.

Comment: PKCS #7 is not an encryption algorithm. It's Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard. The question was about cipher.

Comment: There is EncryptedData in CMS, too.

Comment: @zacheusz - sure, but based on OP's comment "I know that I can do this manually by additionally computing a hash on the encrypted file, but I'd like to avoid doing that", I believe he is just looking for an easy-to-implement solution that includes both a strong cipher and a verification algorithm. A PKCS7 library would provide both with little hassle.

Comment: OK - you're right. It can be a way to acchieve it. But IMHO the problem is that we don'know what he want to acchieve ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MAC to validate that the data isn't corrupted or modified. I suggest you read [this](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html).